# Highcharts plot MACD + EMA + Volume

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the examples provided on highcharts & trying to plot EMA, MACD & Volume. However nothing gets displayed for MACD. Here's what I've tried so far - [chart](https://codepen.io/thandle11/pen/XWgeodm)

```
Code sample in the chart link above
```

Also, in case of adding multiple panels, is there a way to auto fit all the panels instead of specifying height in percentage?

I'd appreciate any help here please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macd indicator is displayed in the second pane, but comparing to the volume series, the values are very small and macd is just a flat green line.

You need to assign the macd indicator to a different y-axis.

```
series: [..., {
  type: 'macd',
  yAxis: 2,
  linkedTo: 'aapl'
}, ...]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Loqrua4w/

---

As to your second question:

> Also, in case of adding multiple panels, is there a way to auto fit
> all the panels instead of specifying height in percentage?

There is no such logic in Highcharts, but you can easily calculate percentage values by your own script.

Comment: In case you can help, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69185756/reproduce-attached-pyplot-chart-using-highcharts

Comment: Hi @usert4jju7, I am glad that I could help. I see that your second question is not related with Highcharts?

Comment: it is & it isn't. It is in the sense that I'm trying to produce a highchart plot. Once I can, statically generate a beautiful highchart for the plotly graph, then I can simply echo the contents  (JS + HTML) into a file & only change the data for the different stocks. So, the request i to take the data in that chart & produce a highchart. I'm new to this javascripting world & am doing my best to learn up & implement which is proving to be a pain. So, please if you can help  with anything at all, I'd receive it with great humbleness

Comment: The question is closed. Could you create a new one with a more detailed description of the problem?